# C++/Win32 How to create an Egg-Timer

Tags: c++, winapi, timer

Heey, i've been thinking about making some sort of timer, like an egg timer. I think it's a good way to get more used to win32 aswell. Well, the idea so far is a normal window, small and simple, with a "Start" and an "Exit" button. If i were to click at the "Start" button, it would start a timer which would countdown from maybe like 5 minutes or so and when it reaches 0, it stops and make a sound. Now, i wonder how i would be able to make so that the window actually counts, and if possible, create a progressbar. If someone could give me a little help, just something small so i have something to work with would be really nice :) I've looked around on Google and timers seems a little strange to be honest :/
Also, is it possible to add Custom sounds, like a .wav or .mp3 for the countdown end sound?

Thank you so much in advance :3

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`SetTimer` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to start a periodic timer - each time it fires you'll receive a `WM_TIMER` message. In the handler for that message, decrement your counter and use [`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to cause the window to be repainted.

Answer (score 0):

Here I know how to make a timer, it is very easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("Color A");
    long long int time;
    cout<<"Enter the amount of time."<<endl;
    cin>>time;//how many seconds you want
    cout<<time<<'\r'<<flush;
    while(time>10)//repeat this until the time in under 10 seconds
    {
        Sleep(800);
        time--;
        Beep(500,200);
        cout<<time<<'\r'<<flush;
    }
    while(time>3)//repeat this until the time in under 3 seconds
    {
        Sleep(500);
        Beep(800,166);
        time--;
        Beep(800,166);
        cout<<time<<'\r'<<flush;
        Beep(800,166);
    }
    while(time>0)//repeat this until the time is up
    {
        Sleep(100);
        Beep(1000,150);
        Beep(1000,150);
        time--;
        Beep(1000,150);
        Beep(1000,150);
        cout<<time<<'\r'<<flush;
        Beep(1000,150);
        Beep(1000,150);
    }
    cout<<"times up!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The system`("Color *letter or number*");` changes the color of the text, the Beep(*tone*, *time*); plays a sound.

Hope it works!